# Progress bar is only showing 100% in blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload for aws s3 upload

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, blueimp

I am trying to integrate /jQuery-File-Upload plugin for uploading files in AWS s3. Till now i am successful in uploading files to S3 via this plugin. But while uploading file to S3 , this plugin is not showing progress bar or to be accurate, it is showing directly 100% as well as file size (for ex.) 128kb/128kb.
I am using servlet(for s3 upload process) and html(temporary as interface).
Here is my servlet ::

```
  /**
  * Servlet implementation class UploadCon
  */
  @WebServlet("/UploadCon1")
  @MultipartConfig
  public class UploadCon1 extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /**
  * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
  */
  public UploadCon1() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }


   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String bucketName = "thehexa4";
    String uploadFileName="";   


    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());   



                    try {
                        for(Part filePart : request.getParts()){
                            if(!filePart.getSubmittedFileName().isEmpty()){
                        String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
                        InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();


                         System.out.println("filePart :: "+filePart);
                            System.out.println("file Name :: "+fileName);


                        System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
                        ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
                        meta.setContentLength(filePart.getSize());
                        meta.setContentType("image/jpg");                           
                        s3client.putObject(bucketName, fileName, fileContent, meta);


                        //JSON metadata transfer

                        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
                        response.setContentType("application/json");
                        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
                        try {

                                    String fileUploadPath = "https://"+bucketName+".s3.amazonaws.com/"+fileName;


                                        JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject();
                                        jsono.put("name", filePart.getSubmittedFileName());
                                        jsono.put("size", filePart.getSize());
                                        jsono.put("url", fileUploadPath);
                                      //  jsono.put("thumbnail_url", fileUploadPath);
                                        jsono.put("delete_url", fileUploadPath);
                                        jsono.put("delete_type", "GET");
                                        json.put(jsono);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        } finally {
                            writer.write(json.toString());
                            writer.close();
                        }

                    }
                        //JSON transfer ends

                            }   

                    }catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
                        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which " +
                        "means your request made it " +
                        "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response" +
                        " for some reason.");
                        System.out.println("Error Message: " + ase.getMessage());
                        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
                        System.out.println("AWS Error Code: " + ase.getErrorCode());
                        System.out.println("Error Type: " + ase.getErrorType());
                        System.out.println("Request ID: " + ase.getRequestId());
                        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
                        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which " +
                        "means the client encountered " +
                        "an internal error while trying to " +
                        "communicate with S3, " +
                        "such as not being able to access the network.");
                        System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
                        }

                    //code ends
                }       
}
```

Here is html :[i haven't changed anything in original plugin html other than form action="/UploadCon1" and necessary js-css file paths so i have displayed just form portion of my html file]

```
    <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
<form id="fileupload" action="UploadCon1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="span7">
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        </div>
        <!-- The global progress information -->
        <div class="span5 fileupload-progress fade" >
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- The extended global progress information -->
            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
    <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
    <br>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
</form>
```

Can anyone help with this?
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you share what yo’ve tried so far? Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry about that, now i have updated my que with required files. Please check them and give the solution if possible :)